# TSQL Select number of rows from table A that have at least one record in table B for each minute of Timestamp from table B

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm new in SQL queries and I have a situation that I don't know how to solve it.
I have two tables like:

```
Table B
Id AId  Timestamp (datetimeoffset(7) column)
1  1    2017-08-31 08:25:32.7000000 -07:00
2  2    2017-08-31 10:25:32.5000000 -05:00
3  2    2017-08-31 10:25:32.9000000 -05:00
4  8    2017-08-31 10:25:32.5000000 -02:00
5  1    2017-05-30 18:31:43.8000000 +03:00
6  7    2017-05-29 18:31:43.8000000 +03:00

Table A
Id   Name
1    AA
2    AB
7    AC
8    AD
```

What I've tried is this:

```
select DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, p.Timestamp), 0) as TimestampMinute, count(1) Count
from A a
cross apply (select top 1 b.Timestamp from B b where a.Id=b.AId) p
group by DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, p.Timestampl), 0)
order by DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, p.Timestampl), 0)
```

but my problem is that it should add the offset and after that to round at minutes and count the number of rows from table A that have at least one record in at that minute, but it just rounds to minute, ignoring the offset and I think that that's the problem why it counts bad. 
So, for date `2017-08-31 15:25` I should have 2 rows from table A (Id 1 and 2). Id 1 from table A has the correspondent to row 1 of table B and Id 2 to rows 2 and 3 (apply distinct).

Expected result:

```
2017-08-31 15:25  2
2017-08-31 12:25  1
2017-05-30 15:31  1
2017-05-29 15:31  1
```

I'm trying to learn from mistakes and improve myself, so please be gentle.

Comment: Shouldn't a column in Table B be named `AId` instead of `BId`? This doesn't make sense now.

Comment: @KamilG. You are right. I've edited my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert the `datetimeoffset` to `datetime2` before rounding to minutes, hence the code:

```
convert(datetime2, b.timestamp, 1) -- timestamp is your column from table b
```

Third argument (**1** is there to account for time zone differences and calculate it. If it was **0** it would omit that part and convert it using `+00.00`).

Solution:

```
select 
  DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, convert(datetime2, b.timestamp, 1)), 0) as TimestampMinute , 
  count(distinct b.aid) as cnt
from b
inner join a on b.aid = a.id -- new part
group by DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, convert(datetime2, b.timestamp, 1)), 0)
order by DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, convert(datetime2, b.timestamp, 1)), 0);
```

Outputs:

```
TimestampMinute            cnt
2017-05-29 15:31:00.000     1
2017-05-30 15:31:00.000     1
2017-08-31 12:25:00.000     1
2017-08-31 15:25:00.000     2
```

Comment: Yes, there are actually 3 but 2 with the same AId as foreign key. It should be distinct

Comment: Adjusted my answer to your needs and edited your question to include this information.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's perfect!

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a query like below

<kbd>**[See working demo](http://rextester.com/PSOTRL32339)**</kbd>

```
; with newB as 
(
    select id,Aid,DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, Timestamp)- datepart(tz,Timestamp), 0) as TimestampMinute
    from B
    )

select TimestampMinute, count(distinct Aid) from A join newB B
on A.id=B.Aid
group by TimestampMinute
```